# VB Calculator Program to PowerPoint

Tags: vb.net

Good day, I made a simple calculator program in Visual Basic 2010, is there a way to automatically export the resulting data into a PowerPoint slide?

```
    Imports System.Math
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim Consumption As Double, Days As Double, Hours As Double, Efficiency As Double
        Dim Res1 As Double, Res2 As Double, Res3 As Double, Harvest As Double
        Dim Hundred As Double, SeventyFive As Double, Fifty As Double
        Dim USD As Double, PHP As Double
        Dim input As Double
        Dim totcost As Double, one As Double, two As Double, three As Double
        Dim FinHundred As Double, FinSeventyFive As Double, FinFifty As Double
        Dim dailykwh As Double, dailybill As Double
        Dim kwhfifty As Double, kwhseven As Double, kwhone As Double
        Dim savefifty As Double, saveseven As Double, saveone As Double



        If txtCons.Text = Nothing Then

            totcost = kwhcost.Text

            input = txtrate.Text

            Days = 30
            Hours = 8
            Efficiency = 0.6

            USD = 2000000
            PHP = 50

            Consumption = totcost / input

            Res1 = Consumption / Days
            Res2 = Res1 / Hours
            Res3 = Res2 / Efficiency
            Harvest = Res3 * 6

            txt30.Text = Format(Res1, "Standard")
            txt8.Text = Format(Res2, "Standard")
            txtEff.Text = Format(Res3, "Standard")
            txtHarvest.Text = Format(Harvest, "Standard")

            Hundred = (Res3 / 1000) * USD * PHP
            SeventyFive = ((Res3 * 0.75) / 1000) * USD * PHP
            Fifty = ((Res3 * 0.5) / 1000) * USD * PHP

            txtHundred.Text = Format(Hundred, "Standard")
            txtSeventyFive.Text = Format(SeventyFive, "Standard")
            txtFifty.Text = Format(Fifty, "Standard")

            totcost = Consumption * input
            one = ((Hundred / (totcost * 1)) / 12)
            two = ((SeventyFive / (totcost * 0.75)) / 12)
            three = ((Fifty / (totcost * 0.5)) / 12)

            kwhcost.Text = Format(totcost, "Standard")
            a.Text = Format(one, "Standard")
            b.Text = Format(two, "Standard")
            c.Text = Format(three, "Standard")

            FinHundred = (Hundred / (totcost * 0.5) / 12)
            FinSeventyFive = (SeventyFive / (totcost * 0.5) / 12)
            FinFifty = (Fifty / (totcost * 0.5) / 12)

            txtFinHundred.Text = Format(FinHundred, "Standard")
            txtFinSeventyFive.Text = Format(FinSeventyFive, "Standard")
            txtFinFifty.Text = Format(FinFifty, "Standard")

            dailykwh = Consumption / 30
            dailybill = totcost / 30

            txtDailyCons.Text = Format(dailykwh, "Standard")
            txtDailyBill.Text = Format(dailybill, "Standard")

            kwhfifty = Harvest * 0.5
            kwhseven = Harvest * 0.75
            kwhone = Harvest * 1

            txtCap50.Text = Format(kwhfifty, "Standard")
            txtCap75.Text = Format(kwhseven, "Standard")
            txtCap100.Text = Format(kwhone, "Standard")

            savefifty = totcost * 0.5
            saveseven = totcost * 0.75
            saveone = totcost * 1

            txtSavings50.Text = Format(savefifty, "Standard")
            txtSavings75.Text = Format(saveseven, "Standard")
            txtSavings100.Text = Format(saveone, "Standard")

            txtCons.Text = Format(Consumption, "Standard")
        ElseIf kwhcost.Text = Nothing Then

            input = txtrate.Text

            Consumption = txtCons.Text
            Days = 30
            Hours = 8
            Efficiency = 0.6

            USD = 2000000
            PHP = 50



            Res1 = Consumption / Days
            Res2 = Res1 / Hours
            Res3 = Res2 / Efficiency
            Harvest = Res3 * 6

            txt30.Text = Format(Res1, "Standard")
            txt8.Text = Format(Res2, "Standard")
            txtEff.Text = Format(Res3, "Standard")
            txtHarvest.Text = Format(Harvest, "Standard")

            Hundred = (Res3 / 1000) * USD * PHP
            SeventyFive = ((Res3 * 0.75) / 1000) * USD * PHP
            Fifty = ((Res3 * 0.5) / 1000) * USD * PHP

            txtHundred.Text = Format(Hundred, "Standard")
            txtSeventyFive.Text = Format(SeventyFive, "Standard")
            txtFifty.Text = Format(Fifty, "Standard")

            totcost = Consumption * input
            one = ((Hundred / (totcost * 1)) / 12)
            two = ((SeventyFive / (totcost * 0.75)) / 12)
            three = ((Fifty / (totcost * 0.5)) / 12)

            kwhcost.Text = Format(totcost, "Standard")
            a.Text = Format(one, "Standard")
            b.Text = Format(two, "Standard")
            c.Text = Format(three, "Standard")

            FinHundred = (Hundred / (totcost * 0.5) / 12)
            FinSeventyFive = (SeventyFive / (totcost * 0.5) / 12)
            FinFifty = (Fifty / (totcost * 0.5) / 12)

            txtFinHundred.Text = Format(FinHundred, "Standard")
            txtFinSeventyFive.Text = Format(FinSeventyFive, "Standard")
            txtFinFifty.Text = Format(FinFifty, "Standard")

            dailykwh = Consumption / 30
            dailybill = totcost / 30

            txtDailyCons.Text = Format(dailykwh, "Standard")
            txtDailyBill.Text = Format(dailybill, "Standard")

            kwhfifty = Harvest * 0.5
            kwhseven = Harvest * 0.75
            kwhone = Harvest * 1

            txtCap50.Text = Format(kwhfifty, "Standard")
            txtCap75.Text = Format(kwhseven, "Standard")
            txtCap100.Text = Format(kwhone, "Standard")

            savefifty = totcost * 0.5
            saveseven = totcost * 0.75
            saveone = totcost * 1

            txtSavings50.Text = Format(savefifty, "Standard")
            txtSavings75.Text = Format(saveseven, "Standard")
            txtSavings100.Text = Format(saveone, "Standard")

        ElseIf txtrate.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please Input Rate")


        End If




    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtCons.Clear()
        txt30.Clear()
        txt8.Clear()
        txtEff.Clear()
        txtHarvest.Clear()
        kwhcost.Clear()
        a.Clear()
        b.Clear()
        c.Clear()
        txtHundred.Clear()
        txtSeventyFive.Clear()
        txtFifty.Clear()
        txtrate.Clear()
        txtFinHundred.Clear()
        txtFinSeventyFive.Clear()
        txtFinFifty.Clear()
        txtCap50.Clear()
        txtCap75.Clear()
        txtCap100.Clear()
        txtSavings50.Clear()
        txtSavings75.Clear()
        txtSavings100.Clear()
        txtDailyCons.Clear()
        txtDailyBill.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, there's a plurality of calculations with their corresponding outputs, what I need to do is transfer the results into a Table either in Excel or Powerpoint for presentation purposes.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming. Programming is the opposite of "automatically" doing something. Can you clarify if there is a programming element to this question?

Comment: @Enigmativity By automatically, I meant after clicking "Calculate" on my Calculator, the result(s) will then be exported into a table in PowerPoint(or Excel).

Comment: You should show us your code and what you've tried so far to make this work.

Comment: I have posted the code and as you can see I have no idea on what to add to this code for it perform what it what was requested of me to do.

Comment: Have you looked as the MS Office SDK to see how you can interact with powerpoint files?

Comment: @ADyson Even if I did, I would have no idea, my programming knowledge is still at a beginner level.

Comment: If you could put your data in a DataGridView to some logical order (instead of all those text boxes) it would be possible to move it to Excel. I just got 989 hits on SO searching for DataGridView to Excel.

Comment: you perhaps need to take a tutorial or something then. I bet the documentation has some. This question is a bit too broad and open-ended for StackOverflow - mostly we do bugfixes or short sharp succinct coding questions. This could have a number of plausible solutions. And we are not able to teach programming fundamentals, either, sorry.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is no, there isn't a simple built-in way of doing it. However, after a quick google using "vb.net powerpoint libraries", several probably useful results are found. [This result](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/presentation/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-powerpoint-library/101) might be what you need, but there is also very useful information in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303717/how-to-use-automation-to-create-and-to-show-a-powerpoint-presentation) from microsoft